# Sed switch comment on search string

Tags: bash, sed

I've a sample file:

```
abcd
1234
asdfg
#text = "1234"
text = "1234, 2345"
abc
def.
```

I would like to switch comment #text.* like this:

```
abcd
1234
asdfg
text = "1234"
#text = "1234, 2345"
abc
def.
```

and again:

```
abcd
1234
asdfg
#text = "1234"
text = "1234, 2345"
abc
def.
```

I'm trying to use this command:

```
sed -i '/text/ s/^#*/#/' file
```

but this only # at first occurence of text. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the lines are always next to each other?

Comment: yes - lines are always next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '/^#*text/{s//#&/;s/##text/text/}' file
```

Or, shorter:

```
sed '/^#*text/{s//#&/;//s/##//}' file
```

A `#` is inserted at the beginning of lines starting with `text` (and containing optional leading `#`). In other words :

- `^text` will be replaced with `#text`
- `^#text` will be replaced with `##text` before leading `##` is removed

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "s/^#text/__temp__/;s/^text/#text/;s/__temp__/text/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -e '/^[^text]/ H; /^text/ { s/^text/#text/; x; s/\n#text/\ntext/g; G; s/^\n//g; p; s/.*//; h;}; $ {x; s/^\n//g; p;}'
```

I use:

```
s/^\n//g
```

for clearing trailing hold space new-lines and

```
s/.*//;h
```

for clearing the hold space.